# Running unittests in CMD or python IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.5

I couldn't find answers for this anywhere. Is it possible to run the tests.py with unittests in IDLE or CMD?
For example, if there are 3 tests, 1 failed,2 passed I would get the output like:

```
python tests.py
Test1 failed
Test2 passed
Test3 passed
```

I tried running the file and it gives me only, one **OK**.

```
C:PycharmProjects>python testfin1.py
......
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.002s

OK
```

However I want to get results for all tests, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all tests are passed, you only get details like below where 6 tests ran and all of them passed.

```
C:PycharmProjects>python testfin1.py
......
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.002s

OK
```

In case of error it shows the stacktrace with test name that fails. You can look in detail over [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface).

Comment: If there are failed tests it's only giving me FAILED (failures=2) and the error.

Comment: As mentioned in the docs(link i pasted above), you can run python -m unittest -v test_module to run tests with high verbosity.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If any test fails then you will see the error message for failure. Try this example -

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'foo')

    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```